# Duplicate Deletion Script does nothing

Tags: windows, batch, deduplication

An associate of mine wrote a script for me that should theoretically delete files that have the same name, regardless of their file type. Specifically, it checks mp3, m4a, wma, wav files. However, I've tried it out and it doesn't delete any files. Is there something wrong with the script, or with my computer's settings?

```
@Echo Off
Rem CMD file to look for duplicate media files and delete them.
Rem 1. x.y & x (1).y etc.
Rem 2. x.y and x.z
Rem
Rem Calling: %0 <Directory>
Rem
Rem Defaults to current directory if <directory> is not specified.

Rem Save environment and enable local extensions
SetLocal
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Set media extensions to check in priority sequence i.e. later extension will be deleted if earlier extension exists
Set mediaExts=.mp3,.m4a,.wma,.wav

Rem Get media directory
Set mediaDir=%1
If .%1 == . Set mediaDir="%CD%"

Rem Loop through media files
For /R %mediaDir% %%f In (*.*) Do Call :checkFile %%f
Pause
Goto :eof

:checkFile
Rem If file has been deleted in a previous loop then skip
If Not Exist %1 Goto :eof

Rem Check for name (*).ext etc. and delete if found
For %%d In ("%~dpn1 (*)%~x1") Do (
    Echo Deleting "%%d" because "%1" exists.
    If Not %1 == %%d Del /f "%%d"
)

Rem Check for alternative audio files
Set found=
For %%x In (%mediaExts%) Do (
    If Exist "%~dpn1%%x" (
        If .!found!==. (
            Set found=%~dpn1%%x
        ) Else (
            Echo Deleting "%~dpn1%%x" because "!found!" exists.
            Del /f "%~dpn1%%x"
        )
    )
)

Goto :eof
```

Comment: The script has a mediaExts variable defined, but it's never used. In the CheckFile routine, the `if not exist...` check would fail if there's a space. Should be enclosed in quotes. The for loop in there will never find anything to delete because it checks if the file name passed `%1` has the same name and extension. Redundant check? Not really sure. In other words, doesn't seem as if the script is working as expected. Why not use a GUI based solution? http://yadfr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How should the script handle a situation when you have `abc.mp3`, `abc.m4a`, `abc.wma`, and `abc.wav` all in the same folder?

Comment: @and31415: the first question I would ask the user is, which file do you want to keep? If there are four files with the same name, but different extension, what becomes the deciding factor on which get deleted and which one is kept? Modified on date? Created on date? File size? Then at least you would have a basis. To be honest, while feasible to do what the user wants in a batch script, this program should be authored in a high level language.

Comment: @JSanchez Good point, but if the user has hundreds of duplicate files it wouldn't be practical to ask each time. I think duplicates should be handled automatically, for example by keeping only the `.mp3` copy. That would also help getting a media collection which is as homogeneous as possible.

Comment: @and31415: Then you're assuming that what your program does, is best for the user. And you wouldn't have to ask each time. You would let the user decide what they think is best for them, and then perform the action they want. That's why I mentioned a high-level language, so that existing libraries/functions can be leveraged, instead of trying to code such a beast in a batch script. It's doable...to a point.

Comment: Let me reword that: I think that, *in this particular scenario*, my idea would probably make sense to the OP. After all, the original, non-working script was meant to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sufficiently fluent in Dos to help you, but if your task does not need automatition, you might find that [Duplicate cleaner](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/duplicatecleaner.html) fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I figure might as well give this as an answer.

1. The script has a mediaExts variable defined, but it's never used. It's not just checking media files, it's checking all the files.
2. In the CheckFile routine, the `if not exist...` check would fail if there's a space. Should be enclosed in quotes.
3. The for loop in CheckFile will never find anything to delete because it checks if the file name passed %1 has the same name and extension. Redundant check? Not really sure.

In other words, the script is not deleting anything because it never finds anything to delete. Why reinvent the wheel? Why not use something like this? http://yadfr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Unfortunately, I know close to nothing about programming, so I don't know how to fix the problems you pointed out. It's why I had to ask someone else to write the original script for me in the first place. The program you linked to, as well as many others I've tried, are unable to detect files that have the same name but are saved in different, specified formats. I want to be able to detect and delete only audio files, without deleting anything else in the folders.

Comment: Well, the script as is won't work. And if it had, it could've deleted stuff you didn't want to. I definitely recommend Yet Another Duplicate File Remover, as it won't remove anything you don't want (e.g. it's not automated, which could be a con) and can use filters, such as Music, Video, etc. I could try to fix the script but, unfortunately, it wouldn't be a priority. :-(